# Google Maps Version and Authentication issue

Tags: android, google-maps, authentication

It gives me the following issue even though I have a valid key for version 1 (not intending to use version 2) and a good SHA-1. I also hardcoded the key in the meta tag in the manifest.xml and also in both the google_maps_api.xml files (release and debug). Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Google map console section. Open your project folder and enable your api key.To enable API key [follow this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key) .